# HttpModule and WCF (AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf, httpmodule

I'm hosting WCF services in Asp.net web page in ASP.NET Compatibility Mode 
(**AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed**). I've written simple HttpModule:

```
public class ExceptionInterceptor : IHttpModule
{
    public ExceptionInterceptor()
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.Error += new EventHandler(context_Error);
    }

    void context_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<httpModules>
        <add name="ExceptionInterceptor" type="HttpModules.ExceptionInterceptor, HttpModules"/>
</httpModules>
```

My question is, why after occurence of unhandled exception in service, the code do not enter in `context_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)` function in my module.

What's more, the code do not even enter the `Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)` in **Globals.asax**.
Can someone explain that to me ?

What is the best option for global exception handling in WCF services ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF is not ASP.NET - it might be able to use some of ASP.NET's infrastructure, but it's not ASP.NET per se.

In order to handle errors in a WCF service globally, you need to implement the `IErrorHandler` interface on your service - or plug in a WCF behavior that does this for you.

Check out the [MSDN documentation on IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) - it's quite a simple interface, really. The `HandleError` method is typically used to log the error on the server to keep track of what's going on, while the `ProvideFault` method is used to turn the .NET exception on the server into an interoperable SOAP fault to send that back to the calling client (which might be a non-.NET client that can't really deal with a .NET-specific exception).

Rory Primrose has a [great blog post](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2008/04/07/implementing-ierrorhandler.aspx) about how to package up the IErrorHandler into a WCF service behavior which you can easily add to an existing service just in config - pretty close to magic :-) Also, check out another [great post on the topic](http://steverb.com/post/2008/11/24/Useful-WCF-Behaviors-IErrorHandler.aspx#continue) by Steve Barbour.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've actually yesterday implemented the same solution from msdn. Still I don't why the compatibility mode is not workink for HttpModule but that's actually not the case for me now.

Comment: @Jarek: the HttpModule doesn't work, because a WCF service is **not** an ASP.NET web application. It handles its errors differently.